# I'm trying to apply the len function to an entire column

Tags: python, dataframe, apply

I have this dataframe with the messages from a Whatsapp group for some years (I changed the messages for privacy reasons):

```
Dates   Messages
0   2017-09-11 18:05:00 : I know this guy
1   2017-09-11 20:29:00 : He is great!
2   2017-09-11 21:46:00 : Do he like playing soccer?
3   2017-09-11 21:46:00 : *does\n
4   2017-09-11 21:46:00 : Someone wants to go to beach?
... ... ...
26664   2020-05-21 18:58:00 : I support this team
26665   2020-05-21 19:50:00 : I prefer the other one
26666   2020-05-21 19:51:00 : yes
26667   2020-05-21 19:53:00 : what do you like to play?
26668   2020-05-22 07:42:00 : Basketball
```

I want to know the length of each message and show them as a column. When I type this:

```
df['Messages'].apply(len)
```

They give me:

```
0         31
1         44
2         33
3          8
4        230
        ... 
26664    107
26665     94
26666    113
26667     61
26668     31
Name: Messages, Length: 26669, dtype: int64
```

The problem is when I tried to create and apply the *len* function to the entire column I got a problem:

```
df['Length'] = df['Messages'].apply(len)
```

The problem:

```
C:\Users\Robert\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

Why this is happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: as @mujjiga said it's a warning. The same code worked for me. You might have that column created too. Otherwise, you can use the below solution

Answer (score 1):

Consider [**`Series.str.len`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) without any `apply` call. Pretty much any Python built-in string method is available as a Pandas Series (`object` dtype) method.

```
df['Length'] = df['Messages'].str.len()
# df = df.assign(Length = lambda x: x['Messages'].str.len())
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this to every column, to get a dataframe of all of the lengths?

Comment: Sure, with a [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) call you could where result would be a 1D Series. Give it an earnest try and ask on a separate post if you run into issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[:,'Length'] = df['Messages'].apply(len)
```

It is a warning not an error.

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter notebook gives you warning sometimes if it feels you aren't using the "best" practice. But the operation will be completed nonetheless. You can verify this buy running the command `df.head()` and you'll find the new column has been added.

As mentioned by @Parafait you can achieve your objective in few other ways, but remember that you don't always have to use best practices, just use what works for you.